# Applying flow to submanifold

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, vector-fields

Suppose $N\subset M$ is an embedded submanifold, and $X\in\mathfrak{X}(M)$ a complete vector field that is tangent to $N$. Let $\phi_{X}^{1}$ denote the time $1$-flow of $X$.

What can be said about $N\cap\phi_{X}^{1}(N)$? It seems to me that in general, this should be an open subset of $N$, and therefore an embedded submanifold itself (if nonempty). But I cannot find a clean proof...

Comment: Isn't $\phi^1_X(N)$ an embedded submanifold of $N$ of the same dimension so it must be an open subset of $N$?

Comment: @levap Why is $\phi_{X}^{1}(N)$ contained in $N$? It is when $N$ is closed, but I guess not in general.

Comment: Can't we write down a vector field on the plane for which $\phi^1(S^1)\cap S^1=\emptyset$?

Comment: @TedShifrin It don't think that's possible. Since $S^1\subset\mathbb{R}^{2}$ is closed, integral curves of $X$ starting on $S^1$ stay on $S^1$ for all times. I have in mind exercise 9.2 in Lee (2nd edition).

Comment: That's not right. $S^1$ is not totally geodesic. (I don't own Lee, so I can't look ...)

Comment: @TedShifrin The exercise says that if $S\subset M$ is a closed submanifold, and $V\in\mathfrak{X}(M)$ is a vector field tangent to $S$, then integral curves of $V$ intersecting $S$ are contained in $S$.